# In Access, How to run queries without result message showing?

Tags: ms-access

In Access, there is a message box showing how many rows you have updated after I run the query, can I run the query without showing that message box?

Comment: In VBA? `CurrentDb.Execute "myActionQuery"`. Or manually through the UI?

Comment: how about add "DoCmd.SetWarnings WarningsOff" , what's difference between these two?

Comment: You didn't answer the question. --- http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/action-queries/SuppressWarningMessages.htm

Comment: sorry, In access .

Comment: I tried to coding

Comment: Thanks for the link, it really help!